# "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object" Database connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up an online RSVP for my upcoming wedding. Im trying to adapt my code from using SQLServer to mySQL through GoDaddy's hosting. In my database connection file, I have the following code:

```
<?php


// function to connect to the database

function dbConnect()
{
    $serverName = 'localhost';
    $uName = 'codytaylorbrown';
    $pWord = 'G0Braves!';
    $db = 'BrownWedding';

    try
    {
        //instantiate a PDO object and set connection properties

        $conn = mysql_connect($serverName , $uName , $pWord );
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);


        //return connection object

        return $conn;
    }
    // if connection fails

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

//method to execute a query - the SQL statement to be executed, is passed to it

function executeQuery($query)
{
    // call the dbConnect function

    $conn = dbConnect();

    try
    {
        // execute query and assign results to a PDOStatement object

        $stmt = $conn->query($query);

        do
        {
            if ($stmt->columnCount() > 0)  // if rows with columns are returned
            {
                $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  //retreive the rows as an associative array
            }
        } while ($stmt->nextRowset());  // if multiple queries are executed, repeat the process for each set of results
     die;

//call dbDisconnect() method to close the connection

        dbDisconnect($conn);

        return $results;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        //if execution fails

        dbDisconnect($conn);
        die ('Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
function dbDisconnect($conn)
{
    // closes the specfied connection and releases associated resources

    $conn = null;
}

?>
```

When I open my RSVP.php page, which contains a form and references another php file to post the results to the database, I get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/ctbrown24/public_html/DBConnect.php on line 50
```

I'm not extremely well versed in php and am building my wedding website as a way to learn, so any help with this would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: `mysql_connect` does not return `object`

Comment: I'm assuming this is for a class, is PDO installed on the server?

Comment: You're creating a `mysql_*` connection. Don't use `mysql_*` it's old bad insecure and removed from PHP 7+. It also does not allow using it in an object oriented manner.

Comment: I am using php 5.4 through cpanel via GoDaddy's hosting and have PDO enabled.

Comment: @TaylorCordova then use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php just update their examples

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks! That helped...now I am getting a different error about the connection failing, but I think that has to do with my server name.

Answer (score -1):

You connect to the database in the first step using the mysql API, however you attempt to retrieve a connection object that would be expected if you had been using the mysqli API, which you are not. Your subsequent call to the query method did not work because you are not dealing with a mysqli connection object.

Read this for more information on this topic: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php